# Como puedo enviar un pdf por un servicio POST, estoy usando requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas necesito adjuntar un pdf y enviarlo por servicio con requests hasta el momento tengo algo asi:

```py
files = {
            'document': open('archivo.pdf', 'rb')
        }

headers = {
            'Accept': "application/pdf",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

La respuesta que me da es 504.

Comment: El error 504 indica que el problema está en el backend y no en tu cliente. Ese error significa que el _gateway_ ha tardado demasiado en responder. El _gateway_ es el proceso del lado servidor que debería procesar tu petición. Si tarda demasiado quizás es que "muere" mientras la está procesando. Desde el lado cliente no es posible saber más detalles. Si tienes acceso al lado servidor deberías mirar los _logs_ para ver si encuentras mensajes de error más detallados.

Comment: También puede tratarse de un problema relacionado con proxies. ¿Usas uno?

Comment: Gracias vere que hay en logs del backend para ver que pasa, no creo que sea un error de proxies ya que no uso ninguno.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo logré, habia sido un error en el backend como dijiste @abufalia